# How to get index of certain value in tableView?

Tags: qt, indexing, tableview

in Qt u can get data from index like this 'Index.data().toString()', i need opposite. I have data and i want index.

Is there in Qt some native function? Or i have to map those data in some array for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to obtain the index by data, you have to traverse your table to find corresponding row and column numbers. You can do it manually, or using `QAbstractItemModel::match()` function. For example:

```
QModelIndexList foundIndexes = tableView->model()->match(QModelIndex(),
                                                         Qt::DisplayRole,
                                                         "My String");
```

You can change the function arguments to get search result that better fits your need.

Comment: Im using qt 5.3 it doesnt compile becouse match needs more arguments. What should be int role?

Comment: @MartinKóňa, ah, sorry, I missed the second argument. If you need to search by the text, you can use `Qt::DisplayRole`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: im searching for integer, which role is for that? i cant find it in documentation

Comment: @MartinKóňa, it is 0 in Qt 4.8.x, however I would recommend using `Qt::DisplayRole` enum value.

Comment: im sorry...it works also for integer. my problem was bad start index..thanks for your help and time

Comment: one more question...match function thinks that 1 and 16 matches..i have tried every Qt:MatchFlag but either they match or there are no matches

Comment: @MartinKóňa, did you try the `Qt::MatchExactly` flag?

Comment: using MatchExactly i dont get match. both of values are Int`s..is it becouse QDisplayRole is for strings? it could convert one int to string with '/0' and then they dont match

Comment: @MartinKóňa, it the values are integers, why do you compare them as strings? Use ints instead of strings.

Comment: Qt::DisplayRole The key data to be rendered in the form of text.

Comment: @vahancho I had a question, from the documentation -  `QModelIndexList QAbstractItemModel::match(const QModelIndex & start, int role, const QVariant & value, int hits = 1, Qt::MatchFlags flags = Qt::MatchFlags( Qt::MatchStartsWith | Qt::MatchWrap )) const` and in the description **Returns a list of indexes for the items in the column of the _start_ index where data stored under...** Here for a tableVIew you have returned `QModelIndex()` for the first parameter, but how did know what value to return? More specifically how did you deduce that for tableView we have to return `QModelIndex()`

Comment: @sami1592, if you use an invalid model index (`QModelIndex()` constructs the invalid one), it will start searching from the top level node in case of tree view or cell at row 0 column 0 in case of tables.